# ColdFusion ~ Class must not be an interface (OSX only)

Tags: java, macos, coldfusion

I'm creating a credential object using the Google API Java Client.  The following code works on Windows, but throws an error on OSX 10.10.3 (Yosemite).

```
<cfscript>
    httpTransport = createObject("java", "com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport").init();
    jsonFactory = createObject("java","com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory").init();
    credential = createObject("java", "com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder").init();
</cfscript>
```

I am able to call createObject on some of the classes with no issues( NetHttpTransport, JacksonFactory, etc.), but when I try to instantiate a credential Builder, I get the following error:

**Object instantiation exception.**

*An exception occurred while instantiating a Java object. The class must not be an interface or an abstract class. Error: com/google/api/client/auth/oauth2/Credential$Builder.*

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/auth/oauth2/Credential
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
...
    at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 60 more
```

The java code that I am ultimately trying to reproduce within ColdFusion is:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(httpTransport)
        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
        .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(KEY_FILE_LOCATION))
        .setServiceAccountScopes(AnalyticsScopes.all())
        .build();
```

[Here's the full Stack Trace](http://pastebin.com/KLHwuff7)

Comment: That is a boiler plate error message for java objects. Can you post the complete stack trace?

Comment: Thanks. The trace says one of the required classes is missing or inaccessible : `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential`.  Verify you have added the jar containing that class to the CF class path - or for CF10+ the [application library path](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-106e125d1353e804331-7ffd.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct access could be working for some of the classes and not for others because the ones it is not working for may be expecting helper classes to be in the classPath. Adding the path to the location of your Google API Java files to your jvm.config file (example jrun4/bin/jvm.config) and restarting the CF Server may fix the problem.

```
# JVM classpath
java.class.path={application.home}/servers/lib,{application.home}/servers/lib,{application.home}/servers/cfusion/cfusion-ear/cfusion-war/WEB-INF/cfusion/lib/oosdk/classes,{application.home}/servers/cfusion/cfusion-ear/cfusion-war/WEB-INF/cfusion/lib/oosdk/lib,{application.home}/lib
```

Comment: Yes, that is what the ClassNotFoundException indicates. One or more classes are missing from the CF class path and/or are inaccessible. In this case `com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential`.  For future readers, the same notes about jvm.config apply to CF10+ (which uses TomCat instead of JRUN), but the file path is different.

Comment: Note, as of CF10+ you can [load jars dynamically](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-106e125d1353e804331-7ffd.html) through Application.cfc. If you are using that approach, then you need to add the missing jar paths to `THIS.javaSettings` instead of your jvm.config file.